# Could the numerical value of mean square error (or root mean square error) tell us something about the rate of convergence?

Tags: monte-carlo, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics

Suppose I have an estimator $\widehat{\theta}$ for $\theta_0$ that is root-n consistent and asymptotically normal. In the monte carlo simulations of many papers that I've read, consistency is usually demonstrated by showing that mean square error (MSE) or root mean square error (RMSE) decreases with sample size n. My question is: could the MSE or RMSE tables also be used to illustrate rate of convergence? In the forementioned example, if $\widehat{\theta}-\theta_0=O_p(n^{-1/2})$, is there a certain pattern of numerical magnitude for MSE or RMSE that I should expect to see? For instance, when $n=100$, should I expect to see MSE be approximtely 0.01, when $n=400$, should I expect to see MSE be approximately 0.025?

My guess is that this is not true. Because $\widehat{\theta}-\theta_0=O_p(n^{-1/2})$ is only saying $\widehat{\theta}-\theta_0=n^{-1/2}Z_n$ for some random sequence $Z_n$ that converges in distribution to normal. This is similar to the deterministic counterpart, $\widehat{\theta}-\theta_0=O(n^{-1/2})$ only implies $\widehat{\theta}-\theta_0=Cn^{-1/2}$ for some constant $C$. Because the $Z_n$ or $C$ could be small or large, for a sequence of $n=100,400,...$ the distance between $\widehat{\theta}$ and $\theta_0$ could be large or small depending on the underlying distribution. There is no pattern of numerical magnitude that we should expect to see. Am I correct?